# Focus not changing even if the focuspointofinterest has changed on iPhone6 and iPhone6+ only

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, iphone-6, avcapturedevice

I am trying to change focus by changing the point of interest as mentioned.

The function always returns a YES and when I use a getter to read the **new focus point of interest, it has changed but isFocusAdjusting = NO**

FYI:

```
 focusMode: AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus

 newFocusPointOfInterest: Normalized CGPoint
```

The focus seems to be locked at (0.5f, 0.5f) or basically AutoFocus

This code has worked on all the devices except iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Has any API call changed?

Please help

```html
- (BOOL)changeDeviceFocusPointOfInterest:(CGPoint)newFocusPointOfInterest
                               focusMode:(AVCaptureFocusMode)focusMode
{
    NSError *error;
    BOOL ret = NO;
    
    if([device lockForConfiguration:&error] )
    {
        if ([device isFocusModeSupported:focusMode] && [device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported])
        {
            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:newFocusPointOfInterest];
            [device setFocusMode:focusMode];
            
            ret = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"focus point setting not supported:{%f,%f}", newFocusPointOfInterest.x, newFocusPointOfInterest.y);
            ret = NO;
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cant lock hardware settings for changing focus point:{%f,%f}", newFocusPointOfInterest.x, newFocusPointOfInterest.y);
        ret = NO;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**EDIT : Additional observations : **

I have checked the sample apps provided by Apple AVCam and AVCamManual
- Tap to focus works on AVCam but not AVCamManual *same device*
I have tried removing code related to the manual control in the sample workspace but it hasn't yielded any results.

- Key Value observations show that there is NO change in lensPosition or focusAdjusting properties
- I have found only one forum post on this problem but none of the work-arounds suggested seem to work https://devforums.apple.com/message/1073042#1073042
- I have tried setting focus to a custom value, extreme and then setting mode to ContinousAuto with required focusPointOfInterest. This triggers focus change but does not focus at the required point of interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as much of an answer as it is a workaround.

From observation, when in AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus mode, the focus triggers a scan and focuses on the required point of interest and then then locks the focus (AVCaptureFocusModeLocked).

If you change mode to  AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus, without changing the point of interest, the camera will perform a full frame focus and so the pointofinterest is rendered useless. (Determined from testing)

To imitate the continuous auto focus behaviour, I use AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification to monitor it manually by changing focus mode to AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus.

However, this is not as fast as AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus and I have observed a time gap of about 2-3 seconds between successive notifications.

If anyone has found a better solution, please share it here.

Note: Default camera of Apple also behaves in a similar manner. The difference lies in the fact that when the camera is moved in the default camera app of iPhone, the focus is set to AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus with (0.5, 0.5) as the focus point of interest.

Comment: The bug has been resolved in iOS 8.3 onwards, realized on running some tests :)

Comment: Do you know why you were getting that 2-3 second gap? Was the `AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification` notification not firing immediately? I am having problems with delay in getting this notification and can't figure out why.

Comment: Since it is a detection of change, perhaps there is a threshold as to how much change triggers the notification?